# JSON - no value for x

Tags: android, json

On Android, I am retrieving a JSON object via the following method;

```
JSONObject tempObj = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");
```

In order to be sure it comes properly, I system out it;

```
System.out.println(tempObj);
```

And it gives the following output;

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "telMobile": "5555555",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "113245",
          "price": "749.0",
          "unitId": 1
        },
        {
          "id": "52589",
          "price": "7.35",
          "unitId": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So, the JSONObject tempObj has a JSONArray named "products" inside, and each product has three fields named "id", "price" and "unitId". However, when I parse this object, I receive a "no value for unitId" error.

```
for (int k = 0; k < tempObj.getJSONArray("products").length(); k++) {
    JSONObject tempProduct = tempObj.getJSONArray("products").getJSONObject(k);
    products.add(new Product(tempProduct.getString("id"), tempProduct.getString("price"),tempObj.getInt("unitId")));
}
```

This is totally senseless. I can obtain the other fields properly. That means when I don't retrieve the unitId and write 1 instead;

```
for (int k = 0; k < tempObj.getJSONArray("products").length(); k++) {
    JSONObject tempProduct = tempObj.getJSONArray("products").getJSONObject(k);
    products.add(new Product(tempProduct.getString("id"), tempProduct.getString("price"),1));
}
```

Then the object is constructed properly. I tried getting it as a String then converting to int as;

```
Integer.parseInt(tempProduct.getString("unitId"));
```

However unitId still gives error. I would think that there would be a problem on the server side but the JSONObject arrives properly since I can see it from logcat output. This is a simple integer how can it cause such an arror? Could there be lying some different problems behind such a case?

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: I was just trying to get unitId from the wrong object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change

```
tempObj.getInt("unitId")
```

to

```
tempProduct.getInt("unitId")
```

Actually you're trying to get value from `tempObj`. That is wrong. There is no value. so instead of get value from `tempProduct`

Answer (score 2):

`unitId` is part of `tempProduct` not of  `tempObj`.

Change

```
tempObj.getInt("unitId")))
```

with

```
tempProduct.getInt("unitId")))
```